# UIScrollView "scroll back"

Tags: iphone

[image]I have a UIScrollView which has a UIView embedded in it. It have 2 buttons "scroll" and "unscroll".On clicking the "scroll" button, my scrollview scroll up from the bottom of the parent view. Everything works fine until here but when I click the "unscroll" button to push the scrollview back to where it came from, nothing happens. I have posted the entire code here. Please check where the fault lies !!. Already spent a sizeable amount of time on it.

```
-(IBAction)unscrollClicked:(id)sender
{
 //[viewController.view removeFromSuperview]; 
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"back to original size" context:nil];

 scrollView.contentSize=viewController.view.bounds.size;


 //scrollView.contentSize=viewController.view.bounds.size;
 [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(IBAction)scrollClicked:(id)sender

{

 //viewController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
 viewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 460);

 //[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

 UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40, 320, 400)];//(0,0,320,160)
 scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

 //[MyView setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 170)];
 viewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
 scrollView.contentSize = viewController.view.bounds.size;


 scrollView.bounces = YES;
 scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
 scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
 scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
 scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
 scrollView.delegate = self;

 [scrollView addSubview: viewController.view];


 [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
 [self moveScrollView:scrollView];
}

-(void) moveScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

{

 CGFloat scrollamount=400;



 [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,scrollamount) animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st problem i see with this code is that you initialize `scrollView` in `scrollClicked` and never store pointer to it, so in `unscrollClicked` pointer should be `nil`. 
Another problem is that as far as i know, animation is conducted this way:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Animate" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

[somView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: hey eviltrue I got it done now. I was a real fool to have been doing it the way I was. I finally did what you have recommended. Although the problem stands resolved, I am curious about the first part of what you have said:-----  "initialize scrollView in scrollClicked and never store pointer to it, so in unscrollClicked pointer should be nil".

Comment: Well, I might miss something, but you define scrollView as local variable in scrollClicked, so it should be missed forever. In other words, I don't where from you get scrollView in unscrollClicked.=)